# Flow of control in this JavaScript program

Tags: javascript

Recently I've jumped into JavaScript programming and yesterday I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/HE6KfMSTHKE) video about mutability and I got totally confused about the program the host wrote.
Here it is:

```js
let newObj = 
{
    total: 65,
    increment: 1
};

const IncrementTotal = function(obj, val)
{
    obj.increment = val;
    return function()
    {
        console.log(obj.total);
        obj.total = obj.total + obj.increment;
        console.log(obj.total);
    };
};

const incBy1 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 1);
const incBy2 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've also added the HTML code from my side.

When the page is loaded and we call `incBy1()` in the browser console, the result is

`65`

`67`

At this point I'm unable to follow the host. He says something like

*by the time* `incBy1()` *executes, the value of* `increment` *is* `2` *and both of them point to the same object*

---

What I'm unable to grasp is why is `incBy2()` called in the first place (we didn't call it)? Is it because it's below `incBy1()`? But then why isn't the data being logged into the console four times (*two times for each*)?

I want to understand how does the program actually execute and why is the output like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I'm unable to grasp is why is incBy2() called in the first place
>   (we didn't call it)?

You didn't call `incBy2()`. But you did call `IncrementTotal` by the below line which increases the value of `obj.increment` :

```
const incBy2 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 2);
```

> But then why isn't the data being logged into the console four times
>   (two times for each)?

That's because you're not invoking `incBy2()` which would have produced two more console logs.

`incBy2` has just been assigned a function returned by `IncrementTotal(newObj, 2)`. Unless you call `incBy2()`, you won't get this returned function executed. However, as soon as you calls `const incBy2 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 2);`, `IncrementTotal` function gets executed and modifies the `obj.increment`

***So this is the flow:***

`incBy1` calls  `IncrementTotal(newObj, 1)` which modifies the object property and returns a function to be invoked. ---Step 1

Then, `incBy2` calls  `IncrementTotal(newObj, 2)` which modifies the object property and returns a function to be invoked. ----Step 2

Now you just call inc1() which executes the function returned in step 1. When this function gets executed, you see the console log printed twice.

Had you invoked `inc2()`, you could see `console.log` two more times for a total of 4 times.

```js
let newObj = 
{
    total: 65,
    increment: 1
};

const IncrementTotal = function(obj, val)
{
    obj.increment = val;
    return function() //let's call it returned function
    {
        console.log(obj.total); //l1
        obj.total = obj.total + obj.increment; //l2
        console.log(obj.total); //l3
    };
};

const incBy1 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 1);//this makes obj.increment to 1
const incBy2 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 2);//this makes obj.increment to 2
incBy1() //When this gets called, the `returned function` is executed and it prints `obj.total` which is 65 `(l1)` and then increases obj.total to 65 + 2 (67) `(l2)` and prints it again `(l3)`.

//incBy2 <------ had you called this you'd have seen the `returned function` getting executed again printing console.log two more times
```

The tutorial is about immutability i.e how you change the original object. Here two functions calls are modifying the original object and I'm sure the host wanted to emphasise, by this example, how mutation can produce unwanted side-effects and that you must avoid mutation of original object. Instead you could create a copy of the object and work on that.

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Could you please tell me when did I call `const incBy2 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 2);` ? Didn't I call the above one?

Comment: When you called `const incBy2 = IncrementTotal(newObj, 2);` you called `IncrementTotal` which modified `obj.increment` and returned  a *function* that you could invoke.

Comment: See the updated answer. hope that further clarifies. Read the *flow* and comments in the code. That will clarify further

Comment: Ah. I think I get it. `IncrementTotal(newObj, 2)` modifies `obj.increment` and makes it `2`. After that when I call `incBy1()` I have `obj.increment=2`. Is it so? If so I got it.

Comment: Yup Exactly! There you go :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assistance. I was very confused about it. I checked you too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215497/discussion-between-abgr-and-user8718165).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a few cosmetic changes to the code can make it more intuitive for you.

In this version, I've renamed the functions and the property names, and I've removed the `incBy2` variable entirely. (See the comments for further clarification.)

```js
// Sets the initial values for the object
let newObj = {
  currentTotal: 65,
  incrementAmount: "we'll set this later"
};

// Defines our main function, which we will call twice
const updateIncrementAndMakeNewFunc = function(obj, newIncrement){

  // Calling the main function will mutate an object's `incrementAmount` property
  obj.incrementAmount = newIncrement;

  // Calling the main function creates this new function, but does NOT call it
  const newFunc = function(){
    console.log(obj.currentTotal);

    // If this function ever gets called, it will mutate the object's `currentTotal` prop
    obj.currentTotal = obj.currentTotal + obj.incrementAmount;
    console.log(obj.currentTotal);
  };

  // The new function will be the output of our main function
  return newFunc;
};

// Calls the main function once
//  - Sets `newObj.incrementAmount` to `1`, -- Great, but this won't last long
//  - Returns a function (which is assigned as the value of a new constant)
const functionThatWasReturnedFromFirstCall = updateIncrementAndMakeNewFunc(newObj, 1);

// Calls the main function a second time
//  - Sets `newObj.incrementAmount` to `2`, -- THIS IS WHY WE EVENTUALLY SEE `67`
//  - Returns a function (which is not assigned to anything, so can't be used)
updateIncrementAndMakeNewFunc(newObj, 2);

// Calls the dynamically created function -- It has never been called till now
functionThatWasReturnedFromFirstCall();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>JS Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```